# Search on multiple fields Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building a search where you can search for someone based on multiple fields. In this case it has to do with names. First Name, Last Name, and a Nickname are all in separate fields.

If a user types in John any first name/last name/ or Nickname with john should appear.

If a user types in John R anyone with a first/last/nickname that matches John and also matches R in first/last/nickname should now appear.

I'm struggling to structure this query using NEST for elasticsearch.

Comment: Its usually a good idea to show some of your code and ask for help.

Comment: Using the rest API you would do the following: `{query: {multi_match: {query: John, fields: [field1, field2...]}}}`, there should be a way to do that on NEST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you do not know how to do multi-field search in elastic or you have some problem with NEST. You can try [cross-fields Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html) to solve your problem :

```
    {
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":       "John",
            "type":        "cross_fields", 
            "fields":      [ "first_name", "last_name", "nick_name" ]
        }
     }
   }
```

if you have a problem with NEST you should post your code.